# Do we need fixed effects in Neural Networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, meta-analysis, fixed-effects-model

I have a background in econometrics, and generally when we are working with panel data (i.e. there's a time-series as well as a cross-sectional dimension), we would include fixed or random effects. Usually this is in the context of working with linear methods though.

I recently started working with some of the ML methods such as Neural networks and random forests. I was wondering how fixed-effects fit into this framework? E.g. do we still need them?

Comment: What would you include if not fixed effects, only random effects?

Comment: are you asking about inference or prediction?  for prediction, the sharing information supported by "random effects" is achieved by L1/L2 regularisation for neural nets and other models eg many recommender systems that use a weighted sum.

Comment: Mainly for prediction yes, I think using NNs would be pretty difficult to use for inference. Interesting that the sharing information supported by "random effects" is achieved by L1/L2 regularisation - I didn't know this. Could you direct me to a source for this?